# how can i change the status to archived classroom with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

```
function get_courses(student) {
  var optionalArgs = {
    studentId: student
  };
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
  var courses = response.courses;
  var active_courses = [];
  if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
      var course = courses[i];
      if (course.courseState == "ACTIVE" && course.ownerId == "owwnerid") {
        active_courses.push(course);
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', course.name, course.courseState);
      }
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No courses found.');
  }
  Logger.log(active_courses);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (course.courseState == "ACTIVE" && course.ownerId == "owwnerid") {
  active_courses.push(course);
  Logger.log('%s (%s)', course.name, course.courseState);
}
```

#### To:

```
if (course.courseState == "ACTIVE" && course.ownerId == "owwnerid") {
  active_courses.push(course);
  Logger.log('%s (%s)', course.name, course.courseState);
  Classroom.Courses.patch({courseState: "ARCHIVED"}, course.id, {updateMask: "courseState"}); // Added
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: courses.patch](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/patch)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a try.

I want to apologize for my English, I'm using google translator.

Comment: @SOPORTE GOOYAM Thank you for replying. If my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @SOPORTE GOOYAM Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.